# dropdown width changing automatically in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textbox and dropdownlist control  in my page.What i did is in my textbox onblur event i append the text in textbox into dropdownlist using

```
if (document.getElementById(pick1).value != "") {
    $("#" + drop1).append($("<option></option>").val(document.getElementById(pick1).value).html(document.getElementById(pick1).value));
}
```

here  drop1 is the id of dropdownlist and pick1 is the id of textbox.My issue is when focusout the text box each time the width of the dropdown decreases automatically and then disappears.This issue is in ie8 and later versions issue is not there

Answer (score 1):

Keep the `select` with an explicit width.

Check using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2fhn/

For IE < 9 : http://jsfiddle.net/X2fhn/embedded/result/

```
<select id="slt"></select>

#slt {
    width: 128px; /* any width that suits your design */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$("#" + pick1).blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $("#" + drop1).append($("<option></option>").val($(this).val()).html($(this).val()));
  }
});
```